# Where can I find information on how to customize the user registration process of Liferay + Sun Web Space Portal

Tags: liferay, glassfish-webspace

I need to quickly customize the user registration form of the liferay/web space portal?  Have not found any direct information on this so would appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

- The source is available, so you might want to patch the existing process
- The API is available (e.g. [see this thread in the liferay forum](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/1371084)), so you can batch-create users or implement your own registration portlet and just use the API. AFAIK you can even register users via a webservice interface.
- You can batch-insert users into the database
- If your existing user data is stored in LDAP, you can connect Liferay to the database.